# Is there a good way of adding the "new" value to the array

Tags: reactjs

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const [array, setArray] = useState([1, 2]);


const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    setValue(3);
    setArray([...array, value]);
};
```

Here i would expect the new array to be [1, 2, 3]

Instead im getting [1, 2, 0]

I now know why this happens, but are there any good ways off working around it?

Answer (score 1):

`value` will not be updated to 3 until the next re-render, so it's still the initial value (`0`) when `setArray` is called. You should assign the value you want to a regular variable and then use that for both.

```
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    const newValue = 3;
    setValue(newValue);
    setArray([...array, newValue]);
};
```

Comment: value has to be defined as state for my program to function

Comment: You're still using state for the actual value, the variable is just used to set the states. Shouldn't affect anything in any program.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that value is not updated yet it will become '3' but in the next render you can simply add the value directly to the array :

```
setValue(3); // if you need to update value for the next render
setArray([...array, 3]);
```